# work out how many times a number divides into another in java and print it out

Tags: java

I need to be able to input two numbers, divide the first by the second and output how many times it goes into it and what the remainder is.

I can print out the remainder but how do I work out how many times the number divides by?
My code is as follows

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TotalAndRemainder
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your first number");
        int firstvalue = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter your second number");
        int secondvalue = keyboard.nextInt();

        int total = firstvalue / secondvalue;
        int remainder = firstvalue % secondvalue;



        System.out.println("The remainder is " + remainder);

    }
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Comment: I'm confused, isn't that pretty much the definition of division, which you're already doing (you call it total)?  12 / 4 = 3 ;  4 goes into 12 3 times.  You've already got the code for that.

Comment: Please exaplin with sample Input and Output.. so that we can modify the code..?

Comment: Yes you're right! :) i couldn't see the wood for the trees. I was thinking I would have to write something else to count how many times I did the division and then print it out. I just need to print out the total variable value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do you already have how many times `secondvalue` goes into `firstvalue`, when you find `total`. You just need to print it out with a statement like so:

```
System.out.println(secondvalue + " goes into " + firstvalue + ", " + total + "times.");
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I guess I was looking too closely at it and not realising I already had the answer in my original code.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(firstNumber + " goes into " + secondNumber + " " + total + " times. The remainder is " + remainder + ".");
```

In java `int\int=int`, i.e. your `total` field already gives you the number of whole times.

Comment: Thanks guys, I guess I was looking too closely at it and not realising I already had the answer in my original code.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TotalAndRemainder
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your first number");
        int firstvalue = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter your second number");
        int secondvalue = keyboard.nextInt();
        if(firstvalue >= secondvalue)
        { 
           int total = firstvalue / secondvalue;
           int remainder = firstvalue % secondvalue;
        }
        else
        {
           int total = secondvalue / firstvalue;
           int remainder = secondvalue % firstvalue;
        }

        System.out.println("The total is " + total + "remainder is " + remainder);

    }
}
```

I hope this will work for u...

Comment: Thanks for the help, I appreciate it. Just started to learn Java and programming in general so it's taking some getting used to.

Comment: Welcome, don't hesitate..... this is the way of learning, keep trying... i hope u will be a expert in no time...

Comment: Well I've got 12 weeks of it for one of the modules for my degree course, but hopefully I will find the time to stick at it and learn more even after the module is finished.